# Ruby On Rails: Using collection_select value in the same form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How would I be able to get the value selected from the collection_select in a form? I want to use this value to dynamically alter the contents of the form. This sounds like it involves javascript but I cannot find any further information as to how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#select_tag_id").change(function() {
        value = $(this).val();
        ....
    })
```